# ASP.NET Core 3.0 WebAPI - why do I still receive InternalServerError when exception is handled in the Controller Method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

When I catch an exception in a controller, the client side still receives an InternalServerError, how can I resolve this?

I have my own 'Result' class, which I can set to failed, and populate with a user friendly error message, I want to catch exceptions in specific controller methods, and send back my failed 'Result' class instead of the code 500 InternalServerError.

Thanks for the help!

```
[HttpGet]
    [Route(Server_DevTestApiEndpoints.INTERNAL_SERVER_EXCEPTION_RESULT_TEST)]
    public Result GetInternalServerExceptionTest()
    {
        try
        {
            throw new Exception();
            return new Result();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return new Result(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well considering a rest api, returning a status code is always a good idea. So does the framework do. However you can use action filter to  do so.

Comment: That solves it, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be better from architectural standpoint to use an `ExceptionFilterAttribute`, that will be responsible for catching all errors in your controller actions:

```
public class LogExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override async Task OnExceptionAsync(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        //log your exception;
        context.Result = new ObjectResult("your custom message")
        {
            StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status200OK
        };
    }
}
```

and just decorate your action or entire controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[LogExceptionFilter]
[Route(Server_DevTestApiEndpoints.INTERNAL_SERVER_EXCEPTION_RESULT_TEST)]
public Result GetInternalServerExceptionTest()
{
    //your action logic
}
```